# oracle database newline character

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

When executing a multi-line statement with \r\n as newline character I get different results with JDBC and SQLPlus.
JDBC will write the \r\n to the DB where SQLPlus only writes the \n.
The JDBC version causes problems when renaming a trigger because the \r\n are stripped.

Can someone tell me if Oracle uses the same newline character on Windows\Mac\Unix or does this depend on the platform?

Sorry for this basic question but I'm not able to find the answer in Oracle documentation.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

After some testing it became clear that all oracle tools like SQLDeveloper, SQLPlus etc. convert the line endings to \n. This might be a bug in oracle JDBC driver.
To avoid the mentioned errors I converted the line endings in my statements to \n and tested it on a Linux and windows server.